# How to align an animated menu using jquery and css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been trying to make a horizontal slide-out menu using CSS & jquery.

The problem(s):
1) CSS - When hovering over the option ('Services' in this case) the rest of the menu is pushed down. I don't know how to get past this.

2) Is there anything I can do so that the menu stays open on the active option? i.e. if the user clicks 'Services 1' the menu will stay open (fully slid-out).

I saw this on Stackoverflow, it seems to have the same problems I'm describing:
http://dabblet.com/gist/3635623/f69409ee9ee7e6613b7ed098a6a82b6a5445ed07

Finally, my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/LJ4tH/13/

HTML:

```
    <nav>
    <ul id="menu-nav">
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="has-flyout"><a href="#">Services</a>
    <ul class="flyout">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Service 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Service 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
```

JQuery:

```
(function navslider($) {
    $('.flyout').hide();
    $('.has-flyout').on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            $(this).find('ul.flyout').stop().animate({width: 'toggle'},1000);
        },
        mouseleave: function(){
            $(this).find('ul.flyout').stop().animate({width: 'toggle'},3000);
        }
     });
})(jQuery);
```

CSS:

```
    nav li { display: inline-block; }
    /*li a:hover { margin-top:0px; }/*This doesn't seem to work*/
    .flyout { display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap; margin-top: 0px; }
    /*ul.flyout li.active { margin-top: 0px; }
    ul.flyout. li. a:hover { margin-top: 0px; }*/
```

Thanks

Fabs

Comment: For the first point I don't understand what you mean cause in your fiddle the menu is pushed down only if the size of the window is not big enough, which is normal.

Comment: Have a play around with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LJ4tH/14/). Don't have more time to finish.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
(function navslider($) {
    $('.flyout').hide();
    $('.has-flyout').on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass("active")) return;

            $(this).find('ul.flyout').stop().animate({width: 'toggle'}, 500);
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass("active")) return;

            $(this).find('ul.flyout').stop().delay(500).animate({width: 'toggle'}, 500);
        },
        click: function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LJ4tH/20/

Not seeing the issue with the items getting pushed down except, like Dim3i said, when the document isn't wide enough.

Comment: @Dim13i & Shmiddty, thanks for the responses. The behaviour I'm describing is as follows (assuming a big window on jsfiddle):

Comment: : 1) In the 'results' window, everything is aligned to the top left, with no space. All good so far. 2) User hovers over 'Services' (which has the flyout) 3) as the flyout moves out to the right, the top-level menu gets pushed down a few pixels. With regards to my second issue, will it help if I change the state to click instead of hover? mod of my original [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qg68n/7/) and modification of Shmiddty's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fV4uG/12/)

Comment: @Fabs what browser? Not happening for me in Win7 chrome.

Comment: Firefox. Seems to be ok in Chrome. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yAsHF/4/) float:right on the .flyout, someone fixed it for me.